# convert int YYYYMMDD to date AS400

Tags: sql, excel, db2, ibm-midrange

I need to convert an integer to a date format in AS400.

I have the field called `ivdat8`, which is integer in the formatted `YYYYMMDD`.

I need to use a WHERE clause to select data between two dates, today and 3 days ago.

I am using the below line to do this:

```
Where
    ivdat8 Between (Select current date - 3 days from sysibm.sysdummy1) And (Select current date from sysibm.sysdummy1)
```

The current date from sysibm is a true date format, but ivdat is integer.

How can i cast ivdat8 to be a date format i can use within the WHERE clause ?

I have tried the below to convert the int to date:

```
cast(cast(A.ivdat8 as varchar(50)) as date)
```

&

```
TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(ivdat8,'YYYYMMDD')
```

Comment: Can you do `ivdat8 between cast(varchar_format(current date - 3 days, 'YYYYMMDD') as int) and cast(varchar_format(current date, 'YYYYMMDD') as int)`?

Comment: Side note: you should usually query date/time/timestamps with a lower-bound inclusive - `>=` - upper-bound exclusive - `<` style.  For one thing, I'm a little suspicious of anything that's blanket including 'today', given _today is never finished_ (only yesterday).

Answer (score 4):

Actually it's better for performance not to convert the `ivdat8` column data, but do this with parameters like below.

```
select ivdat8
from table (values 
  int(to_char(current date - 2 days, 'YYYYMMDD'))
, int(to_char(current date - 5 days, 'YYYYMMDD'))
) t (ivdat8)
where ivdat8 between 
    int(to_char(current date - 3 days, 'YYYYMMDD')) 
and int(to_char(current date, 'YYYYMMDD'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way to do it without causing a complicated conversion in the query is to use this:

```
cast(digits(cast(A.ivdat8 as dec(8))) || '000000' as date)
```

The full where clause doesn't need to select from sysibm.dummy1 either.

```
where cast(digits(cast(A.ivdat8 as dec(8))) || '000000' as date) between current date - 3 days and current date
```

If you have indexes built on ivdat8 though, the fastest selection will be:

```
where A.ivdat8 between cast(Current date - 3 days as dec(8)) and cast(Current Date as dec(8))
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to convert the int to a date, first i had to cast it as a string, then use `TO_DATE`

```
To_Date(cast(A.ivdat8 as varchar(50)),"YYYYMMDD")
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Where cast(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(cast(ivdat8 as varchar(8)), 'YYYYMMDD') as date)                                                        
      Between (current date - 3 days) and current date
```